# need help to understand this situation

Tags: javascript, function

```
function doSomething(a) {
    b = a + doSomethingElse(a * 2);
    console.log(b * 3);
}

function doSomethingElse(a) {
    return a - 1;
}

var b;

doSomething(2); //15
```

I don't understand why the result is 15; can someone explain to me how should I think in this kind of situations?

Comment: What do you think the value of `a` is in `doSomething` when `doSomething(2)` is called, and why? How about the other variable named `a` in `doSomethingElse` when `doSomethingElse(a * 2)` is called?

Comment: `why the result is 15` what do you think it should be? I mean, it's 15 because maths, right

Comment: by the way, to be technical, the result of calling doSomething is `undefined`

Comment: I'm still interested to know that the *expected* result was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doSomething(a) {
    b = a + doSomethingElse(a * 2);
    console.log(b * 3);
}

function doSomethingElse(a) {
    return a - 1;
}

var b;

doSomething(2); //15
```

When you call `doSomething(2);` you pass `value 2` to your function `doSomething(a)` so value of a inside this function is `a = 2`.

Now you have `b = a + doSomethingElse(a * 2)` with `a = 2` it's `b = 2 + doSomethingElse(4)` correct ?

In your `doSomethingElse(a)` function you pass `value 4` so `a = 4` inside that function. It returns `a - 1` so if `a = 4` it will return `3`.

Now back to `b = 2 + doSomethingElse(4)` since `doSomethingElse(4)` returns `3` the result is `b = 2 + 3`.

In your next step you're printing out `b * 3` -> `console.log(b * 3)` which results in `15`.

This is because values of `a` are local within a functions scope, you can check this for reference:

[Javascript Scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)

Answer (score 6):

doSomethingElse() is called with parameter 4(a*2). It returns 3. (3+2)*3 = 15

```js
function doSomething(a) {   
      b = a + doSomethingElse(a * 2);
      console.log('params of a', a, doSomethingElse(a*2));
      console.log(b * 3); 
}

function doSomethingElse(a) {   
      console.log('params b', a);
      return a - 1;  
}

var b;

doSomething(2); //15
```

Comment: just a minor correction: `doSomethingElse` is called with `4` as *argument*, not *parameter*. The parameter is just `a` (the same of `doSomething` by the way).

Answer (score 4):

> can someone explain to me how should I think in this kind of situations?

The best way is to use the debugger built into your IDE and/or the one built into your browser. Put the code in a page, put a breakpoint on the `doSomething(2)` call at the end, and then step through the code, watching the values of `a` and `b` as you go along. Using a debugger is a fundamental skill to learn very early on, not an advanced skill.

What's happening here is:

- `b` is declared globally (and initially has the value `undefined`), because `var` declarations are processed before anything else in the scope (this is sometimes called "hoisting").
- `doSomething(2)` is called.
- It calls `doSomethingElse(a * 2)` where `a` is `2`.
- `doSomethingElse` returns `3` because `a - 1` is `4 - 1` is `3`.
- That `3` is used where `doSomethingElse` was called, so the line containing that call is in effect `b = a + 3` where `a` still has the original `2`. So `b` gets `5`.
- `console.log(b * 3)` outputs `15` because `5 * 3` is `15`.

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong but I think the part that you possibly don't understand is when you call

```
    doSomethingElse(a * 2)
```

This part isn't acting like "execute doSomethingElse with 'a' argument, then multiply it with 'a*2'. 
What happens here is you pass 'a*2' as argument, which in your scenario is 4.
doSomethingElse will return 3 as a result of 4 - 1.
var b is now 5 as result of 2 + 3.

Answer (score 0):

Easy one, you give 2 in doSomething, so b = 3 + doSomethingElse(4). Then in doSomethingElse : 4-1 = 3, so it return 3, so b = 2+ 3

and you do (2+3)*3 = 15

sumary : doSomethingElse is executed before the display of b * 3,and a value isn't changed at all, so you add doSomethingElse result with a and then multiply the result by 3